# What is the correct generic name for the data structure in a calculator app that holds the numeric display

Tags: data-structures, naming-conventions

It would hold a string and have characters (numeric, or decimal point) added and removed from the right end. Ignore the case of negative numbers for simplicity.

Does this kind of data structure have an agreed-upon name? Register? Buffer? Display? Something else?

**UPDATE:** This is an internal representation and may not be the final form of some calculation. It may be the inputs to some later calculation (after turning it into a number, of course).

Comment: I would call it: Result.

Comment: In relation to your edit: in my OMGWTF (http://omg.thedailywtf.com/) submission, my "internal representation" is called CalcEval, which is a class with member variables `state`, `result`, `memory`, `funcmap`, `buffer`, `visitor`, `display_text`, and `stack`. You probably won't need all of that for your program though; I was trying to make mine over the top, for the contest. :-P

Comment: `state` is the state machine state, `result` is the calculation result, `buffer` is where the digits get entered into, `memory` implements "M+", "M-", etc., `funcmap` defines what all the buttons do (can be static), `visitor` is used to implement the Visitor Pattern (don't ask; I was trying to make the submission gnarly), `display_text` is an event object used to trigger the view's display of the result (MVC for the win!), and `stack` is for implementing operator precedence (because I decided I wanted that too :-P). So, you choose which ones you want to use for yours. :-P

Comment: @Chris_Jester-Young This doesn't seem so bad. Could you tell me what's over the top about it?

Comment: To me, a basic calculator doesn't need to be MVC, nor does it need to use the visitor pattern. Those were "features" I put in to make the entry more "enterprisey". :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement it using a stack. A stack is last-in-first-out (LIFO), just like what you're describing with the display.

But if you're looking for something to name your calculation results, I'd agree with most of the answers that said "result" or "display". :-P

Comment: 'buffer' from your comment looks like what I'm talking about. Can't pick a comment as the answer so I'll pick this answer. I guess it's pretty subjective based on the range of answers I got, though.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say there's an "agreed-upon" name; after all, I doubt there's a standards body whose job it is to review these things. That said, maybe you'll find one of these acceptable:

- Answer
- Result
- Value
- Digits

Answer (score 1):

I think "Display" would make sense if you were describing it in real-world terms.